# Predicted Mass of Hypothetical Graviphoton

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, supergravity

In (some) supersymmetry theories, a spin-1 gravivector or graviphoton is predicted (but has not yet been observed) to exist. My question: is there a consensus among theorists as to the mass (if any) it is expected to have, and if so, what range of masses is it speculated to have?

Any specific papers that discuss the matter would be appreciated (but not required).

Comment: recent paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321319301233

Comment: @annav That article was extremely helpful. It's led me to further articles, and it's clear that there's no consensus on the issue, across the various supergravity models. I'll do further research and probably answer my own question.